# PHP omits a return

Tags: php, tags, return

when a carriage return follows a closing php tag, php doesn't print it.

How can I change this?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 6):

That's normal behavior, and cannot be changed : the newline after a closing `?>` is always ignored.

Here's the reference, in the FAQ of the PHP manual : [Hey, what happened to my newlines?](http://fr.php.net/manual/en/faq.using.php#faq.using.newlines) 

*(quoting, emphasis mine)*

```
<pre>
<?php echo "This should be the first line."; ?>
<?php echo "This should show up after the new line above."; ?>
</pre>
```

> In PHP, the ending for a block of code
>   is either "`?>`" or "`?>\n`" (where `\n`
>   means a newline). 
> So in the example
>   above, the echoed sentences will be on
>   one line, **because PHP omits the
>   newlines after the block ending**. 
> This
>   means that you need to insert an extra
>   newline after each block of PHP code
>   to make it print out one newline.
>   
> Why does PHP do this? 
> Because
>   when formatting normal HTML, this
>   usually makes your life easier because
>   you don't want that newline, but you'd
>   have to create extremely long lines or
>   otherwise make the raw page source
>   unreadable to achieve that effect.

And here are a couple of interesting reads about this :

- [Rules pertaining to HTML or whitespace preceding or following PHP tags](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Complete_PHP_Programming/Escaping_from_HTML#Rules_pertaining_to_HTML_or_whitespace_preceding_or_following_PHP_tags)
- [PHP Stripping Newlines](http://shiflett.org/blog/2005/oct/php-stripping-newlines)
- [The history of PHP eating newlines after the closing tag](http://brian.moonspot.net/php-history-newline-closing-tag) *-- goes back to PHP 3 ^^*

Comment: In fact, nowerday it advised to not use the closing tag at all (on the end of the files)

Comment: Not quite true Frenck.  It's advised not to use the closing tag in your application code.  If you're using PHP as a template language it's impossible NOT to use the closing tag.

Answer (score 0):

It's a default behavior of the language.

If you need the line break, you put a `echo "\n"` or `echo "<br>"` as the last line of the script.

Answer (score 0):

This is intended behavior (see [Escaping from HTML](http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phpmode.php)):

> […] when PHP hits the `?>` closing tags, it simply starts outputting whatever it finds (except for an immediately following newline - see [instruction separation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.instruction-separation.php) ) […]